# PuppeteerSharp - querySelectorAll + click

Tags: c#, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer-sharp

I'm brand new to puppeteersharp. Can you please tell me where, in my thought process and code, I'm going wrong. I'm trying to grab reviews on this product:

https://www.newegg.com/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-2060-gv-n2060oc-6gd/p/N82E16814932115

All reviews load when you click the reviews tab which is retrieved from

`document.querySelectorAll(".tab-nav")[4]`

reviews is null after this code:

```
            using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options))
            {
                using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    await page.GoToAsync("https://www.newegg.com/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-2060-gv-n2060oc-6gd/p/N82E16814932115");

                    var clickReviews = "document.querySelectorAll('.tab-nav')[4].click();";
                    var reviews = "Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.comments-content'));";

                    await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync(clickReviews);
                    var reviews = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync(reviews);
                    Console.WriteLine(reviews);
```

Answer (score 2):

`EvaluateExpressionAsync` won't return DOM elements. You should build a serialized output. For instance, a `string[]` with the review text.

```cs
var reviews = "Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.comments-content')).map(r => r.innerText);";
var reviews = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync<string[]>(reviews);
Console.WriteLine(reviews);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm running into another issue now. Would you know why reviews is null still; however, when I run it in the debugger, it returns the correct result?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. However, I'm still a little lost.
Without rendering javascript, the class "comments-content" (the class that shows each review) loads 8 reviews. So, I need to click on the reviews tab which loads the remaining 17 reviews. I fixed my issue by awaiting for "comments-content" to load again.
But, why is this? Didn't comments-content already exist before clicking? Why did I have to await it?